# Jquery Ajax in Laravel 4 - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

.Hello y'all. I'm trying to learn ajax and am currently trying to have an input in a form be sent via a route to a controller and then echoed in a div.

For some reason I am getting a `NotFoundHttpException` error when I press the submit button for the form and am having trouble seeing what is wrong with my route.

If anyone can point out where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

View:

```
<form id="edit_price_form" method="POST" action=""> 
    <input name="new_price" id="new_price"/>
    <input type='submit' class='button tiny radius' id='edit_price_button'/>
</form>
```

Ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit_price_form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //form_data
        var form_data = $('#edit_price_form').serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'edit_prices',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data){
                $("#edit_results").html(data);
                $("#edit_results").addClass('panel callout radius');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Route:

```
/*Ajax Edit Price on Price Page*/
    Route::post('edit_prices', array(
        'as'    => 'edit_prices',
        'uses'  => 'PriceController@edit_prices'        
    ));
```

Controller:

```
public function edit_prices(){

        $new_price = Input::get('new_price');

    echo $new_price;
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: What is the url of the page you are displaying the form?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your HTTP method. You're AJAX request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'edit_prices',
    type: "PUT",
    ...
```

But your route looks like this:

```
Route::post('edit_prices', array(
    'as'    => 'edit_prices',
    'uses'  => 'PriceController@edit_prices'        
));
```

In short, you'll need to change your AJAX request from `PUT` to `POST` - Laravel is rejecting the `PUT` request because it's expecting `POST`.

Comment: Ooooh, okay. I was updating so I thought that the correct method was PUT.